# Scapy multithreading scans slowly

Tags: python, multithreading, scapy

I'm writing a multithreading port scanner using scapy,
I create a process to use scapy's sniffer, and use multithreading to send syn packet,but I found the maximum speed of a scanner is 100 times per second,it is too slow.
So I use other way:

```
response = sr(IP(dst=targetIP)/TCP(dport=port, flags='S', timeout=1))
```

I found sr is slower than using send and sniff

My main code is as follows:

```
def prn(self,pkt):
    ip = pkt.sprintf('%IP.src%')
    port = pkt.sprintf('%IP.sport%')
    info = '{0}:{1}'.format(ip,port)
    fileipinfo =  '{0}:{1}\n'.format(ip,port)
    if (int(port) in self.portlist) and (info not in self.result):
        self.result.add(info)
        lock.acquire()
        FileHelper.append(self.savepath,fileipinfo)
        model = dict(ip=ip,port=int(port),flag=self.data_flag,createdatetime= datetime.datetime.now())
        SqlHelper.add(model)
        lock.release()

def listen(self,portlist):
    self.portlist = portlist
    sniff(filter="tcp[13:1] & 18==18", prn=self.prn) #iface=self.ifacestr


def send(self,param):
    ip = param['ip']
    port = param['port']
    send(IP(dst=ip) / TCP(dport=port, flags='S'), verbose=False)

    self.sendcount = self.sendcount + 1

    sys.stdout.write('\r' + 'Scanned:{0},Remaining{1}'.format(self.sendcount, self.taskcount - self.sendcount))
    sys.stdout.flush()


def run(self):
    time_start = time.time()
    scannerparam = self.scannerparam
    if scannerparam.save:
        RESULT_PATH = scannerparam.save
    params = []
    iplist = IpHelper.get_ip_list(scannerparam)
    portlist = PortHelper.get_port_list(scannerparam)

    p_listen = Process(target=self.listen,args=(portlist,))
    p_listen.start()

    for ip in iplist:
        for port in portlist:
            params.append({'ip':ip,'port':port})
    self.taskcount = len(params)

    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=scannerparam.threadnum) as executor:
        param_left = len(params)
        param_iter = iter(params)
        jobs = {}
        while(param_left):
            for param in param_iter:
                job = executor.submit(self.send,param)
                jobs[job] = param
                if len(jobs) > scannerparam.threadnum:
                    break
            for job in futures.as_completed(jobs):
                param_left -= 1
                #result = job.result()
                del jobs[job]
                break

    time_end = time.time()

    time.sleep(20)
    p_listen.terminate()

    if scannerparam.validator:
        self.validate(scannerparam)

def validate(self,scannerparam):
    if 'proxy' in scannerparam.validator:
        proxy_validator = ProxyValidator(self.data_flag)
        p_proxy = Process(target=proxy_validator.run)
        p_proxy.start()
        p_proxy.join()
```